# impedance match with rectifier

Tags: impedance-matching, bridge-rectifier

I have a AC source with some serial resistance. To maximize power transfer, the load connect in series should be 40 ohms (its a voltage regulator). However it need to take a DC voltage rather then AC, so I use a full bridge with a smoothing capacitor. But I dont know how to match the load (to 40 Ohms) with the capacitor present.. It always reduce the power transfer as it provided a parallel path..

Any advice would be helpful

Comment: Why are you after maximum power transfer if you are using a voltage regulator?

Comment: "Maximum power transfer" implies 50% efficiency and is NOT what you want in an AC power supply. Design for maximum efficiency (minimum wasted power) instead. (Maximum Power Transfer is useful, e.g. when your power source is strictly limited such as an antenna where you want to maximise the received signal, but not useful as I understand your description here.

Answer (score 1):

You have confused your requirements. The rule "load impedance equals source impedance for maximum load power" applies when the source impedance is fixed. In your case you can reduce the source impedance, so you need to consider other issues. Let's say your power supply has a 10 volts output with a .01 ohm impedance. Then the maximum load power will indeed occur with a load impedance of .01 ohms. However, the output current will be $$i = \frac{V}{2R} = \frac{10}{.02}= 500\text{ amps}$$ and the total power dissipated will be $$P = Vi = 500\text{ amps}\times 10\text{ volts} = 5000\text{ watts}$$ which is not exactly a useful number for a power supply, since it says that the power supply will dissipate 1 watt for every watt in the load, and the power supply will be very inefficient.

Instead, what you need to look at is minimizing the amount of power dissipated in the power supply, and here your concerns about the 40 ohms is perfectly correct. Let's say your rectifier (with an output capacitor to give something like DC) puts out 10 volts, and your load resistance is 10 ohms. Since the output resistance is not fixed, what is the effect of changing it? The answer should be obvious. The lower the source resistance the higher the load voltage and the higher the load power.

So, yeah, get rid of the 40 ohms. It's not helping.